# calling a function passed as an argument without parentheses

Tags: python

I've got a relatively large programme which I've split into modules - as a result there's a lot of overlap between the functions in different modules which I am currently working on removing.

One of the issues I've come across is the need to pass functions and classes as arguments to other functions and classes - before they've been defined.

I'm aware I could pass a function name as a string and use exec(), I could also in theory use dictionaries with standardised keys. However I want to know how to call a function just by using it as an object in another functions arguments.

I know multiple functions and classes take parentheses-less functions as arguments and call them - so I'm sure it's possible. the question is how?

basic example would be:

```
def func1(some_function):
    #call some_function here
```

and in a separate module:

```
def func2():
    print("Success!")
```

the final result would be:

```
>>>func1(func2)
'Success!'
```

I'm using Python 3.4. I'm also assuming that what would work for functions would work for classes.

Comment: wow that simple... gotta love Guido!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def func1(some_function):
    #call some_function here
```

simply becomes

```
def func1(some_function):
    some_function()
```

Functions are *first class objects* in python.

Comment: Went with this in the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here this is what i did, of coarse you can substitute `a` for any name

```
def func1():
    return "ess"
def func2(x):
    return "succ" + x

a = func1()

print func2(a)
```